# Are there any changes required from a wallet's perspective regarding the Versioned Transactions?

Tags: web3.js

I was wondering if I need to change any thing on the wallet's end that supports Solana network, with the new Versioned Transactions that are going to come into play. According to this link, https://edge.docs.solana.com/de/developing/versioned-transactions, I only need to change something if I connect to the Solana RPC using `maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0` option, otherwise it will continue using the legacy transaction version.

Please let me know as soon as possible and thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you don't make that change, if you make an RPC call - such as getTransaction(s) - that *would* return a v0 tx, the call will error. If you are confident you'll never be calling getBlock / getTx on a v0 tx, then you should be fine.